# Evaluate $g(2)$ and $g(5)$ for a function

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $g(x)=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \rceil x^n$ (the ceil function). Then, evaluate g(2) and g(5). g(x) Being a function representation of a series, I just have to substitute x=2, and x=5 separately. However, I was not able to find the answer, I tried expressing the function in terms of derivatives and integrals, and it did not work. At the end someone told me that it should be $g(2)=\frac{1}{3}$, $g(5)=\pi$. So...is this correct?

Comment: Doesn't the series diverge when $x = 2, 5$? This is probably a generating function of some other function, but I'm only assuming.

Comment: Yes, that's only defined for $|x|< 1$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the generating function
$$\frac{1}{x^3-x^2-x+1}=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+\cdots$$
Therefore substituting $x=2$ would yield $\frac{1}{3}$ but substituting $x=5$ would not yield $\pi$, instead it should be $\frac{1}{96}$.

Comment: By the way the above series only converges when $|x|<1$.

Comment: This is the analytic continuation of power series.